# R integrate\sapply three variables function

Tags: r, function, sapply, integrate

I have the following problem:
I consider a two entries function (fvec) and I want to integrate it wrt one variable (i.e. x). Therefore I do;

```
fvec = function(x, y) sapply(x, function(z, y) z-y, y=y) 
gvec = function(x) sapply(x, function(y) integrate(fvec, lower=2, upper=3, y=y)$val)
```

Then I eveluate gvec when y=2

```
a=gvec(2)
```

and the code works.

However if I introduce a third variable and I try to apply the same procedure:

```
fvec = function(x, y, w) sapply(x, function(z, y, w) z-y+w, y=y, w=w) 

gvec = function(x,t) sapply(x, function(y,w) integrate(fvec, lower=2, upper=3, y=y, w=w)$val)

b=gvec(2,2)
```

R gives me the following error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument "w" is missing, with no default

I can't understand why and I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in this line

```
gvec = function(x,t) sapply(x, function(y,w) integrate(fvec, lower=2, upper=3, y=y, w=w)$val)
```

you call the variable t in the beginning and later you call it w. This version works as intended:

```
gvec = function(x,t) sapply(x, function(y,w) integrate(fvec, lower=2, upper=3, y=y, w=t)$val)
```